# Network Sniffer for Windows that attaches to a process

Tags: networking, sniffer

I'm in a need of network sniffer that attaches itself to a process in Windows 7 and sniff through it's networking like ... where it is sending packets to what the packets contain what packets it is receiving basically all the network traffic between that selected process and the server it is sending packets to.

I already downloaded tools like Rawcap and SmartSniff but they either don't work as intended or they throw some errors while trying to attach to the process.

I also tried wireshark but it sniffs my whole traffic not per process base

Answer (score 1):

I know a freeware-Capsa Free which may cover your needs. But they request you to register to download. http://www.colasoft.com/download/products/capsa_free.php

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like Unix's 'strace' command :) Please find Microsoft Process Monitor here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx , give also a try to xperf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff190983%28VS.85%29.aspx

Good luck! :)

Comment: I don't see how can you attach Process Monitor to only 1 process O_O It also makes my PC unstable.

Comment: Ok I've found the app i was looking for 
http://wpepro.net/

Hope i help someone in the future